# VS 2015 Use Gulp to Compile Less

Tags: gulp

I am trying to set up a similar process to what Web Essentials offered in the old visual studio in the newest one. For those of you who aren't familiar with how that worked, the process was:

```
File Setup:
    a.less
        a.css
            a.min.css
            a.css.map

     b.less
        b.css
            b.min.css
            b.css.map
```

So basically when you open a.less and start editing it, it would automatically check out a.css, a.min.css, and a.css.map as well. Then when you save, it would recompile the 3 sub files as well as saving the less file.

I am able to replicate this by writing a separate task for each file like so:

```
gulp.task('checkout', function () {
    return gulp.src('Styles/brands.css')
        .pipe(tfs());
});


gulp.task('less', ['checkout'], function () {
    del('Styles/brands.css');

    return gulp.src('Styles/brands.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Styles'));
});
```

This uses gulp-tfs-checkout to checkout the sub file, and then the less to compile. This works 100% how I expect it to. I can set up a watch to watch the less task and everything will work great. The only problem is, how do I expand this to handle all my less files in that folder? I could write separate checkout and compile tasks for each file, but that's not really ideal.

I am used to writing projects where saving any less file compiles and concats all of them into a single or a couple files, but this is a work project and for multiple reasons I need to keep the css files separate as they are now. We use visual studio's bundling, but its an older project and people have referenced the css files randomly outside of the bundling process so it would be a pretty big/risky task to change that.

I don't know how to watch many files, but only change the current one if that makes sense.

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src('Styles/*.less') //watch all of my files
        .pipe(tfs())//checkout only the css file for the less file that was changed here somehow
        .pipe(less()) //compile only the css file that was changed
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Styles'));
});
```

I am fairly used to grunt and gulp, but like I said I generally do things in bulk on my project. I'm not sure how to do this when I want to watch all the files, but only change 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create all those tasks per each file dynamically? You can read the contents of the folder where your less files are with fs.readdirSync and then if the file is a less file you create for each the task 'checkout' + filename and then 'less' + filename. 
Being dynamically you will not have any problems when you create a new less file or when you remove one.

Comment: I would like to do this as well.  Any chance you could share your full gulp file, to save me some time?  Thanks!

Comment: What Michael says, it would be great to see an example of your solution

Comment: our gulp tasks have evolved overtime, so we don't have something like this. But I tried to give you an example of how it could be done here (code doesn't compile): https://gist.github.com/lcostea/abc3d326a2d33676b617

Comment: Kevin can you please share a working code, if you possible ?

Comment: @LiviuCostea
Can you guys give solution of your gulp file to checkout TFS files only when they are modified not all files
gulp.task('build-less', () => {
    return gulp.src('Content/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/Content'));
});

How do I checkout only modified file in build folder which is styles.css when I modify file in src folder styles.less